# Dynamic text in Animate CC and URL mapping

Tags: dynamic, jquery-animate

I am having trouble figuring out how to work with dynamic text. I have to create an ad for 6Sense and map company names to URL's. 6Sense gave me some code to incorporate into my html and js files but how do I link it to the dynamic text in Animate? Does the instance name for the dynamic text need to be specific? I am totally lost. This is part of what they gave me to incorporate into the html.

var companyUrlMapping = { "UW Medical": "
https://www.uwmedicine.org/
", // Key is used as custom "OHSU": "
https://www.ohsu.edu/
", "Virginia Mason": "
https://www.virginiamason.org/
", "Seattle CCA": "
https://www.seattlecca.org/
", // add your additional // [Company Name]: "Click URL"};

In the image below the yellow text is what will change to the company name.

Any help would be appreciated!

[banner screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXnie.png)

I haven't been able to get that far.